# Слэш в регулярных выражениях

Tags: php

Есть корзина. При добавления товара в корзину проверяется регуляркой имя товара. Если оно подходит то добавляется. Но вот имя товара KONOV BC\BD 768 не добавляется, т.к. есть \ . Вот шаблон регулярного выражения `var $product_name_rules    = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я()-,.!&';` Как добавить в него \

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильное регулярное выражение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574927/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: в самой регулярке должно быть две обратные косые, но php требует эскейпить каждую из них - и того четыре

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить экранированный \, то есть "\\"

```
$product_name_rules = '\\\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я()-,.!&';
```